# Actionbar and toplayout scroll when keyboard open

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, android-actionbar

I've created listview with edittext.

if i use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest file only ,i able to edit text field.

if not , unable to edit text.

But if i use "adjustpan", the actionbar and toplayout also scroll.

How to prevent the actionbar and toplayout scroll when keyboard open.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "adjustResize", and when you notice that the keyboard is shown (link [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) to know when it occurs), you'd act accordingly.

For example, if you have a chatting app, you could do as was done on WhatsApp and Hangouts, so that if you are on the bottom, you will scroll to the bottom.